# Installing Angular component router via JSPM results in mysterious 404 errors

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, systemjs, jspm

I have a `JSPM/Typescript/Angular 1.5.3` project. I want to use [the new component router](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router). In my project dir, I used the command

```
jspm install npm:@angular/router
```

which installed fine with no errors. I then added it to my `app.ts` file with

```
import ngComponentRouter from 'jspm_packages/npm/@angular/router@0.2.0/angular1/angular_1_router'
```

But when I start my `lite-server`, I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/instruction.json

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/utils.json

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/url_parser.json
```

I'm not sure why it wants to load these mysterious JSON files, so I checked my package.json:

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "name": "app",
    "dependencies": {
      "": "npm:@angular/router@^0.2.0",
      "angular": "npm:angular@^1.5.3",
```

Hmmm...that empty `""` doesn't look right. I feel like there's a build step missing if JSPM can't resolve a package name and the router is asking for JSON files. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I get the same 404s, but my jspm dependencies shows the (expected?) `"@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router@^0.2.0"`. Still no closer to a resolution though.

Comment: @Squiggle Do `jspm uninstall @angular/router` and then try `jspm install npm:ngcomponentrouter`

Comment: I tried using that, but I'm getting an error `Component "Root" has no route config.` - which either means I need to configure something that isn't documented in the guide, or it looks like this is the wrong version. Did you get it working OK?

Comment: Working now. Thanks!
The error was quite misleading - whilst I had set the root component, I had not loaded a module which contained a referenced component. (facepalm)